# distribution order

Tags: distribution-theory

let $m\in \mathbb N$ and define $T : C_c^\infty (\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $T(\phi)=\phi^{(m)}(x_0)$.Then show that $T$ is a distribution with order "m".

i had proved that $T$ is a distribution as $|T(\phi)|\le Sup|\phi^{(m)}|$ where $\phi \in C_C^\infty (K)$ and $K$ is compact in $ \mathbb R $. From here it is clear that order of the distribution is $\le$ m but i am not able to get why it is equal to m.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with $\phi^m$? Is it supposed to be the $m$th derivative of $\phi$, usually denoted by $\phi^{(m)}$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes it is the $m$th derivative of $\phi$

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $\phi^{(m)}$ then the order is $m$ almost by definition :

Find $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ such that $T(\phi) = \phi^{(m)}(x_0)= 1$ and let $\phi_\epsilon = \epsilon^m \phi(x_0+(x-x_0)/\epsilon)$.

Then $\sum_{n =0}^{m-1} \|\phi_\epsilon^{(n)}\|_\infty = \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ while $T(\phi_\epsilon) = 1$ thus $T$ can't be a distribution of order $< m$.

Comment: i didn't get this proof like what your $\varphi$ is and even what your $\phi$ is. Can you please elaborate and write it properly.

Comment: @bunny I wrote a new answer specially for you.

Comment: sorry @user1952009 i hadn't refreshed your new answer. Now the solution is fine to me and thanks for the help.